# Images not displaying in new wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

Just installed fresh copy of Wordpress 3.4.1.

No plugins, no aftermarket themes. Just using Twenty Eleven.

http://14glenbrook.com/?p=5

Images are not showing at all. It uploads to the correct directory in wp-content/uploads, and when ftp'ing in I can see the images are there in the folder. But nothing is being displayed. Also gives a 404 error when clicking on the image placement on the page. Checked folder permissions, they seem to be correct '711', not sure what else to look at.

Any help appreciated,

Ken

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Folder permissions on 'month' and 'year' were incorrect. Changed to 755, everything fixed.